# c++ get factory method to be thread safe

Tags: c++, multithreading, factory-method

i have this c++ simple factory method :

```
class Vehicle {
public:
    virtual void printVehicle() = 0;
    static Vehicle* Create(VehicleType type);
    virtual ~Vehicle(){}
};
    Vehicle* Vehicle::Create(VehicleType type) {
        if (type == VT_TwoWheeler)
            return new TwoWheeler();
        else if (type == VT_ThreeWheeler)
            return new ThreeWheeler();
        else if (type == VT_FourWheeler)
            return new FourWheeler();
        else return NULL;
    }
```

I want that this factory method will when called from more then 1 thread be protected and return New Object to the caller thread only . other threads will wait
in java i guess its something like :

```
synchronized (Vehicle .class) {
   .. protected code ...
}
```

How can it done in c++14 ?

Comment: This method __is__ threadsafe.

Comment: As in, the default global allocator is thread safe.

Comment: The return value is only ever returned to the caller. what makes you think other threads could get the object?

Comment: @tkausl how come ? can't more then 1 thread call the factory method in paralele ?

Comment: If those 'TwoWheeler()' etc. ctors are thread-safe, you should be OK, yes.  Is there some reason for your doubt?

Comment: The data within a function (local variables) are always private to a thread. Each has their own copy. Therefore you don't have to protect anything. What you have to protect is shared read-write data (read-only is fine). Your code does not feature any of that. Examples that could come up are a) shared objects such as the same object being modified from different threads b) static class attributes c) global variables

Comment: @Homer512 how i do protect that ?

Comment: You store an [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and lock it at the start of the method with an [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock)

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177784/is-it-possible-to-have-java-like-synchronization-statements-in-c-c